# How to combine objects in a list based on the previous object?

Tags: python, list

I have a list of ordered sub-lists, which contain two string objects.

```
mylist = [['x1','red'],['x2','blue'],['x2','green'],['x1','yellow']]
```

I am trying to find a way to initiate the following rule;

```
for sublist in mylist:
    if sublist[0] == sublist[0] - 1
        combine sublist and sublist - 1
```

In other words, I need the first string in each sublist to be checked against the first strig in the preceding sublist, and if the two match to combine them; resulting in the following:

```
mySortedlist = [['x1','red'],['x2','blue','x2','green'],['x1','yellow']]
```

Note: I am only interested in the immediately preceding sublist, and not if the item has appeared elsewhere in the list.

Update: Based on a helpful comment from another User, it is worth me pointing out that my actual data-file is many thousands of lines of text, of which these anomalies could appear anywhere.

Comment: you only appear to be appending the 1st and 2nd indexes together, do you really need a loop? `[my_list[0], my_list[1] + my_list[2], my_list[3]]`

Comment: The actual data-file I have is thousands of lines of text. So I would need something that can iterate over the entire file.

Comment: Try `itertools.groupby` with key being first element. `I am only interested in the immediately preceding sublist, and not if the item has appeared elsewhere in the list.` - if you don't sort it, it will group only the ones next to each other. (x1, x2, x2, x2, x3, x2 -> x1 with 1 elem, x2 with 3 elements, x3 with 1, x2 with 1)

Comment: What is ˋif sublist[0] == sublist[0] - 1ˋ supposed to mean?

Comment: It was intended to mean: "look at the first object in the sublist and compare it to the sublist immediately preceding it"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to find the consecutive elements:

```
from itertools import chain, groupby
from operator import itemgetter

[[*chain.from_iterable(v)] for _,v in groupby(mylist, key=itemgetter(0))]
# [['x1', 'red'], ['x2', 'blue', 'x2', 'green'], ['x1', 'yellow']]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
from itertools import groupby

mylist = [['x1','red'],['x2','blue'],['x2','green'],['x1','yellow']]

[[j for i in v for j in i] for k, v in groupby(mylist, key=lambda x: x[0])]

#[['x1', 'red'], ['x2', 'blue', 'x2', 'green'], ['x1', 'yellow']]
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote a quick thing. Its not too complicated if you just step back and think about what "if sublist[0] == sublist[0] - 1" would look like in actual code. 
The one stumbling block is probably the try-except block to deal with the first item in the list (the first item will raise an "Index out of range" error)

```
mylist = [['x1','red'],['x2','blue'],['x2','green'],['x1','yellow']]

mylist2 = []
for sublist in mylist:
    print(sublist)
    print(mylist2)
    try:
        if sublist[0] == mylist2[-1][0]:
            mylist2[-1].append(sublist[0])
            mylist2[-1].append(sublist[1])             
        else:
            mylist2.append(sublist)
    except Exception as e:
        if len(mylist2) == 0:
            mylist2.append(sublist)
        else:
            raise e

print(mylist2)
```

---

-->

```
['x1', 'red']
[]
['x2', 'blue']
[['x1', 'red']]
['x2', 'green']
[['x1', 'red'], ['x2', 'blue']]
['x1', 'yellow']
[['x1', 'red'], ['x2', 'blue', 'x2', 'green']]
[['x1', 'red'], ['x2', 'blue', 'x2', 'green'], ['x1', 'yellow']]
```